# MySql.Data.MySqlClient C# console app

Tags: c#, mysql, console

I am using:

```
                string selectString =
                "SELECT username, password " +
                "FROM users " +
                "WHERE username = '" + user + "' AND password = '" + password + "'";

                MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(selectString, Program.mySqlConnection);
                Program.mySqlConnection.Open();
                String strResult = String.Empty;
                strResult = (String)mySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                Program.mySqlConnection.Close();
                if (strResult.Length == 0)
                {
                    responseString = "invalid";
                    InvalidLogin = true;
                } else {
                    InvalidLogin = false;
                }
```

and at strResult.Length I get a NullReferenceException for some reason.

Comment: FYI, the password column is a hashed version of the password, and not the actual password. Testing against it would require you to compare input via the `Password()` function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password

Comment: Additionally, ExecularScalar expects exactly one column of one row to be returned. At the very minimum, this query is returning two columns: username and password.

Comment: Warning: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!

Comment: @LynnCrumbling, it isn't a hashed password if he didn't hash it when inserting it.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling, yup! My natural gas company stores passwords plaintext.  I did the forgot password process on their site, and it emailed me my password in plaintext :(

Comment: @Oded You can't tell that by the short code I posted since you don't know whenther I checked for injection before that or not.

Comment: I dont know why are you using strResult.Length??

Comment: @Gromer *sigh* I hope you don't opt to pay your bill online, lest they're talking to their payment gateway without https....

Comment: @Vijay Yeah.. I was wondering what the point of that was, too.

Comment: @Max0999 - The standard way to protect against SQL injection is to use parameterized queries. I don't know what you did, but I can see string concatenation - this is a warning sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how your code should look like:

```
using(var connection = new MySQLConnection(connectionString))
{
    using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = @"
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM users
WHERE username = @user AND password = @password";
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySQLParameter("user", user));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySQLParameter("password", password));

        var total = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
        if(total == 0)
            InvalidLogin = true;
        else
            InvalidLogin = false;
    }
}
```

There are few things to notice

- NEVER build your query string in that way you did it. Search on Google for "sql
  injection" to find more about what could happen to you. ALWAYS use
  parameters. I know, you wrote that this is console app, but good habits are important.
- ALWAYS use `using` keyword when working with database
  connections and commands.
- From your code, I have a feeling that you have global MySQLConnection object, right? NEVER do that! ADO.NET uses connection pooling, so opening new connection for your actions is not expensive operation. Make sure that you didn't disable connection pooling in your connection string.
- Not related to ADO.NET, but important: you should hash your password.

To answer your question, the problem is in ExecuteScalar that you are using. It returns scalar variable (single value)...in your query, you are returning username and password, so you should use ExecuteReader instead...but I think that COUNT(*) in the query that I posted, together with ExecuteScalar might be a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
string selectString =
                "SELECT username, password " +
                "FROM users " +
                "WHERE username = '" + user + "' AND password = '" + password + "'";

                MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(selectString, Program.mySqlConnection);
                Program.mySqlConnection.Open();
                String strResult = String.Empty;

                if (mySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()== NULL)
                {
                    responseString = "invalid";
                    InvalidLogin = true;
                } else {
                    InvalidLogin = false;
                }
               Program.mySqlConnection.Close();
```

Comment: I used (strResult == user) instead and everything started working, thanks. BTW I checked for injection. Thanks everyone for being so awesome!

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteScalar()` returns a single value.  You want `ExecuteReader()` because you're bringing back the Username and Password

Comment: hmmmm.  Have a look at Aleksandar Vucetic's suggestion about using Count(*) above, to see if you are getting any data from your query.